# Start multiple datanode in hadoop 2.x cluster

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing

I was able to start up the the hadoop cluster with default configuration in Hadoop 2.2.0. How do I start additional DataNode pointing to the existing Cluster.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by starting up the cluster? How many nodes do you have? The command to start all data nodes in a cluster is: sbin/hadoop-daemons.sh start datanode

Comment: I have two nodes now . 1 name node and 1 data node . How do I start one more data node ?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand. Have you installed hadoop 2.2.0 on both machines and done the required configs for cluster mode? For e.g. We have a 2-node cluster. 1 has namenode, datanode, resourcemanager and nodemanager and the second has just datanode and nodemanager. You have to install the hadoop package on both boxes and do the config and then the datanodes can be started separately via 'sbin/yarn-daemon.sh start datanode' or together via 'sbin/yarn-daemons.sh start datanode' (notice the extra 's' in daemons).

Comment: I have one machine where I have installed the hadoop 2.x . Now when I have started the cluster using start-all.sh which starts  1 datanode and 1 namenode +others. Now in the same machine how do I start another datanode pointing to the exiting Namenode. I have only one box but I want to start multiple data nodes .